# Rails 4 not encrypting cookie contents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, encryption, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello I'm trying to encrypt and secure the data contained in my cookies but It seems like the data only gets encoded (base64)

This is an example:

```
cookies.signed[:example] = { :value => 'can you see this?', :httponly => true, :expire_after => 30.minutes, :secure => true }
```

And this is the content of the cookie:

```
BAhJIhZjYW4geW91IHNlZSB0aGlzPwY6BkVG--b4a8bbd7cd35e392ccd788df0008fd10b48442b2
```

And if I decode the string (base64) I get:

```
I"can you see this?:EFom{q{vq{_M<}to8f
```

I would like to know what I'm missing, currently this is what I have in

session_store.rb:

```
Service::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_service_session'
```

And in my secret_token.rb I have set something like this:

```
Service::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'e892d55cbc205bb6..'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cookis is not encrypted, because you used the [`signed`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies/ChainedCookieJars.html#method-i-signed) method on the cookie jar, which, well, just signes the cookie content.

To encrypt the cookie, use the [`encrypted`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies/ChainedCookieJars.html#method-i-encrypted) method:

```
cookies.encrypted[:discount] = 45
# => Set-Cookie: discount=ZS9ZZ1R4cG1pcUJ1bm80anhQang3dz09LS1mbDZDSU5scGdOT3ltQ2dTdlhSdWpRPT0%3D--ab54663c9f4e3bc340c790d6d2b71e92f5b60315; path=/

cookies.encrypted[:discount] # => 45
```

Answer (score 1):

To piggy-back off of the accepted answer:

Depending on your situation: you might want to consider using a session cookie if you desire encryption. (As the accepted answer suggests: you can encrypt cookies, but perhaps a session cookie is more appropriate).

In rails 4 by default: the session cookie is by default encrypted and signed.

[Relevant Rails Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html).

Specific section:

> If you only have secret_token set, your cookies will be signed, but not encrypted. This means a user cannot alter their user_id without knowing your app's secret key, but can easily read their user_id. This was the default for Rails 3 apps.
>
> If you have secret_key_base set, your cookies will be encrypted. This goes a step further than signed cookies in that encrypted cookies cannot be altered or read by users. This is the default starting in Rails 4.

`secret_key_base` is located in rails 4 by default in: config/secrets.yml.

usage in rails 4:

```
# In rails 4 by default, this will be encrypted and signed
session[user_id] = 1
```