# Encrypted cookies in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, encryption

I am having some problemss knowing the correct (Rails 4) way of using cookies. There is not too much info about it.
I've read these 2 websites:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

[Rails 4 not encrypting cookie contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273735/rails-4-not-encrypting-cookie-contents)

By using the 'encrypted' method of the object 'cookies' you can encrypt it. But I don't know how to get it back decrypted. Another thing: Isn't there a way to encrypt all the cookies with one call? Or should I do it for each one of them?

Example take from the second website.

```
cookies.encrypted[:discount] = 45
```

Although I found this:

https://cowbell-labs.com/2013-04-10-decrypt-rails-4-session.html

Should I use this one? Or there is a common way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't simply use the `session` instead of custom cookies? Would be simpler in my opinion...

```
session[:discount] = 45
```

User will not be able to see this information, because it is stored in the server memory.
This way, you can use just the built-in, easy-to-use `session cookie` that rails automatically gives you.

Comment: Yes you're right and it is the best way to go. I had problems with cookies, since you have to keep track of the type's data and convert it all the time to the correct one when retrieving it.

Still there is a reason that is making me use cookies: Scalability. If I were to have many servers in the future, the session variable will belong to one server. Unless servers were synced (Neither a trivial nor an easy task to do), the next request from the client may be served by a different server that does not have the corresponding session variable. If the client always carry the cookies, no prblm.

Comment: The other approach would be storing data session in the DB (in fact there's a gem: activerecord-session_store), but I am trying to keep DB connections to a minimum.

So the one to go would be cookies in this case I think.

Comment: "I had problems with cookies, since you have to keep track of the type's data and convert it all the time to the correct one when retrieving it". This is not true in scripting languages like ruby, you won't need to do castings or similar operations. Just take and use it. You know what is inside what ;). About the scalability, you're right, but this way you'll need to put EVERYTHING in cookies. If you're using gems like Devise, this will not be easy... Just to point it out, you have another possible approach to keep the DB clear: take a look to `memcached`.

Comment: Whenever I had to retrieve for example 'cookies[:score]', I had to make a conversion: 'cookies[:score].to_i'. If I don't do that, when performing an addition (for i.e) it would just raise an exception for trying to apply an operation on a string and an integer. --

I finally made it another way by just encrypting it via OpenSSL class, by using a symmetric key. I have to encrypt each cookie. For the next request I recieve, I have to decrypt them all before actually do something with them. --

I am not sure memcached will work this time. Cookies change for each request I do. (Im doing a game)